# can't load index after refresh route params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I create routing for may web page like this

```
angular.module("ui",[]).config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider,$httpProvider)
{
  $routeProvider.when('/home',
  {
     templateUrl: 'home.html'

  })
  .when('/login',
  {
    templateUrl: 'login.html'

  })
  .when('/sign_in',
  {
    templateUrl: 'create_account.html'

  })
  .when('/profil',
  {
    templateUrl: 'profil.html'

  })
  .when('/note/:id',
  {
    templateUrl: 'view_note.html'

  })
  .when('/editNote/:id',
  {
    templateUrl: 'edit_note.html'

  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

and the server side code (expressjs)

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) { 
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html')
});
app.get('/note/:id', function(req, res) { 
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html')
});
app.get('/note/*', function(req, res) { 
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html')
});
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) { 
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html')
});
```

so all of my routing configuration run perfectly but when I try to refresh my page almost all of my page run normal except the page with `/editNote/:id` routing configuration. so how to fix this server side routing problem (expressjs)

[image]

Comment: So, what's the error?

Comment: You don't have to set new route for every single path. Leave just one, and set it to `*` (express)

Comment: @Patryk I already try changing '/*' to '*', but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I can figure out the real problem, it cause of the same name of route between mongoose route and express/angularjs route. so I change the angularjs route name

Answer (score 0):

On the server file add:

`app.use('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});`

and **remove**

```
app.get('/note/*', function(req, res) { 
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html')
});
```

Comment: Even if you remove all your  '/*',  ? happen I've never worked with an url like that one.

Comment: finally I can figure out the real problem, it cause of the same route  between mongoose route with express/angularjs route. so I change the angularjs route name